# ArgumentError: Job arguments to CarrierWave::Workers::ProcessAsset must be native JSON types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I would like to become more closely aligned to the latest Sidekiq version but I'm not sure what I need to upgrade or update in my code/libraries. Any ideas?

[image: error message]

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs inside [Carrierwave Backgrounder gem](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder). Sidekiq's latest `strict_args!` mode strictly requires that strings be passed instead of symbols and the gem is passing symbols as this wasn't previously a requirement.

As issue was created for this [here](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder/issues/304) and was resolved in version `0.4.3`

In your gem file require the new version or greater.

```
gem 'carrierwave_backgrounder', '~>0.4.3'
```

Then run `bundle install` to update it and that should resolve the issue.